# How do I create issue in Jira On Demand with HTML formatting?

Tags: html, jira

Our team use emails to create issues in *Jira on Demand*. I just wonder if we can use HTML formatting in those emails? If yes, how to enable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Incoming mail to JIRA can be text or HTML. No enabling should be needed. Outgoing mail has a default set in JIRA Admin, then each user can change it in their profile.